# method returning wrong variable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This class I'm working with has three instance variables I'm interested in, NSmutablearrays xArray yArray and zArray, there are also other NSmutablearrays, a, bArray and c.
I just added accessors

```
- (NSMutableArray *) xArray {
   return xArray;
}
```

ditto for y and z.
However, it's returning yArray, zArray and bArray for some reason.
Why is that happening?

---

Okay, I just changed the names of the methods to GetXArray and everything seems to be returning the right variables. Now I'm really confused. How the heck did this happen and how do I prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: We'd have to see more code to be able to say what's happening; the accessor method shown above is perfectly valid. How are you setting these variables?

Comment: all the arrays are declared in the header in one line:
NSMutableArray *aArray, *bArray, *xArray, *yArray, *zArray;

When initiating the class, I call a method to read from file one line at a time, then add each value to the array.
[xArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:x]];




It's not a file-reading problem. When I did NSLog(@"objects: %@ %@ %@", xArray, yArray. zArray), the correct arrays were printed.
However, the method xArray returned yArray upon being called. When I changed the name of the method to GetxArray, things were right again.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Did you build and analyze?

Comment: As BJ Homer said, we need to see more code to really know what's going on, though I'd guess there's some issue with how/where the instance variables are defined or initialized; bbum's suggestion to Build and Analyze would certainly help highlight a number of possible issues.

Comment: Yeah, went through with the debugger. Is there a cocoa convention against having methods sharing a name with a variable? I couldn't find anything documentation that said so.

Comment: There is exactly the opposite convention, actually.  You need to post more code-- where the objects are initialized at the least-- and any compiler warnings.

Comment: "Build and Analyze" is a specific action in the build menu in Xcode under 10.6 that does more processing of your code than just building and can give useful information.  Are you working on 10.6 (doesn't matter if you're targeting 10.6, just using it yourself)?  Have you run "Build and Analyze"?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straight forward setting/getter stuff:

**XYZArray.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface XYZArray : NSObject {
  NSMutableArray *x;
  NSMutableArray *y;
  NSMutableArray *z;
}

-(NSMutableArray*) x;
-(NSMutableArray*) y;
-(NSMutableArray*) z;

-(void) setX:(NSMutableArray*)newArray;
-(void) setY:(NSMutableArray*)newArray;
-(void) setZ:(NSMutableArray*)newArray;
@end
```

**XYZArray.m**

```
#import "XYZArray.h"
@implementation XYZArray
- (id)init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
      x = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      y = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
      z = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
  [x release];
  [y release];
  [z release];
  [super dealloc];
}


-(NSMutableArray*) x
{
  return x;
}

-(NSMutableArray*) y
{
  return y;
}

-(NSMutableArray*) z
{
  return z;
}

-(void) setX:(NSMutableArray*)newArray
{
  [newArray retain];
  [x release];
  x = newArray;
}

-(void) setY:(NSMutableArray*)newArray
{
  [newArray retain];
  [y release];
  y = newArray;
}

-(void) setZ:(NSMutableArray*)newArray
{
  [newArray retain];
  [z release];
  z = newArray;
}
@end
```

Better still, if you are using Objective-C 2.0 you can do all of this with properties and not write any code at all. Read this for an introduction, http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-properties-setters-and-dot-syntax.html.